# How to read all information from 125 khz RFID card?

Tags: rfid

We are working on a project, where user should be able to access the application via rfid card and PIN.

We have got sample card from client and procured reader from online store, which is following:

http://kitsguru.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=592&search=rfid+reader

This card can be connected to computer and is identified as hid device. It works as keyboard wedge. (When I open notepad and swipe the card over reader, it gives output like `0008011225` , which is unque serial number printed in the card, i can actually read this number in the surface of the card)

Client says this card also store more information about user in it. But we are not able to read it.

My question is:

> How can we read all the information available in the card? Do we need
>   another reader, if yes please let me know more about it, like what it
>   is called etc.

I am not from electronic background.

Comment: Sometimes the extra information may *appear* to be stored on the card, but what's really happening is that the data is stored in a separate database that is indexed by the card's serial number. It may take some digging to determine which it is.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to make sure card doesn't have any other information ?

Comment: "Some digging" means that you need to study the documentation for the reader and for the application (software) that the client is using with it.

Answer (score 1):

It is the reader device that gives you the infomation. The reader is programmed to act like a keyboard and it only gives you the card id. Keyboard communication is one-way. If you want to do more like reading and writing, you'll need another reader device which is capable of reading and writing. Or maybe you can load some firmware to your card-reader-device to act to support two-way communication.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but which reader we should go for? I tried searching online, but none is saying clearly if they can read the data or how much they would read.

Comment: Reader depends on your card. Seems like your're using 125Khz proximity card. AFAIK this card cannot store so much info. I suggest you moving to another platform. For example MIFARE. Mifare cards designed to operate like memory. You can easily find MIFARE reader-writers on the net. I suggest to start with 1K (1 Kbyte) MIFARE card. Check [this](http://kitsguru.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=456) or search google with _mifare card reader writer_

Comment: Unfortunately client is already using this card. We can't change card, but can change the reader.

Comment: Can you get the same reader that the client is already using?

Comment: I would do the same.